# Merge my changes to the same branch as colleague

Tags: git, merge

My friend and I have been working on the same branch. He has committed his changes to our branch, and now I want to do the same.

I already did a local git commit, but I'm not sure what are the steps from this point forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to get your branch up-to-date so that you can push your changes.

First you will do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

You can also just do `git pull` this will cause a merge commit to occur.

Then all you should need to do is:

```
git push
```

And the changes should be on the shared remote branch.

Comment: Claiming that pull (or merge) makes the history "dirty" is a bit biased. There are enough situations when merge commits are quite useful for showing the implementation of a feature that took several steps. Maybe you could update your answer to present the merge and rebase alternatives a bit more neutrally?

Comment: Updated the answer to be more neutral